# How is it possible that state change exists?

Tags: logic, epistemology, metaphysics, time

We observe the passage of time, change in location of particles, reality is changing its state.

Initially the thought arises that if state change ability were derived, created or began to exist, that would be a state change itself.

That's a contradiction, so the ability for state change must be invariant.

How can state change exist given this contradiction?

Comment: "*Time exists so that everything doesn’t happen at once.
Space exists so that it doesn’t all happen to you.*" A variant of a [quip by Ray Cummings](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2019/07/06/time/).

Comment: why do you suppose that an ability is a state? who are you arguing with, what metaphysics and why?

Comment: i think you've confused yourself tbh. some abilities may be states. even if all abilities are states, does that mean that there there is no ability without an infinte regress (contradiction is the wrong term) -1 for getting chat-gpt to rewrite the MMK, which shows that things have **no** essence, not that causal capacities are an essence (IMHO)

Comment: This is a heavy metaphysical question that goes beyond empirical enquiry and into, if one permits, a Kantian examination of how minds fundamentally construct experience. From a constructivist lens, one can say that the experience of change of state is not identical to a purported independent existence of change independent of experience. Thus, there is a change, of sorts, if one assumes the latter, and that is the objective system of change changes to have an agent experience change. That's shooting from the hip. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the infinite causality in Spinoza's ontology.

According to Spinoza, the movement (state change) of all the things in the universe is a chain of causes and effects. And so the question arises: which is the first primordial cause in the chain?

The answer that Spinoza gives is: the universe itself is the primordial cause.

This might seem confusing at first since we are used to think of causes and effects as transient, that is as causes and effects followed by one another (a cause is previous to its effect). But in the first part of its book [Ethics](https://www.marxists.org/reference/subject/philosophy/works/ne/ethics.htm), Spinoza writes this about the universe (he calls it god):

> PROP. XVIII. God is the indwelling and not the transient cause of all things.

Here, by *indwelling* the dutch philosopher means *inmanent* or an effect that exists within the cause itself and ends whenever the cause ends. Think about a fire and light: fire is the cause of light, but light cannot exist without fire they are inmanent (indwelling) to each other.

So Spinoza is saying here that the chain of transitive causes is infinite but that the one cause that all of nature's effect is nature itself.

So to answer the question:

State change is infinite. The universe wasn't static before and then started moving but it has always been in movement. There is no beginning or end of the universe because it is caused inmanently by itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Initially the thought arises that if state change ability were derived, created or began to exist, that would be a state change itself.
> That's a contradiction...

I had to read this question some 3 odd times to figure out this paragraph. Heh!!

It sounds confused but behind that confusion there's a key insight:

### State cannot be a property of the universe

So then?! Is there no such thing as state?

I would expand your insights as follows

1. *State is not a property of the universe but of our models*
2. *Models are simplifications of the universe, usually extreme simplifications*
   Ignoring this leads to confusing [map with territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation)
3. *There are usually multiple maps for the same territory*
   Think the multiple [alternate projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) — really distortions — for maps
4. *Changing state requires an invariant background/framing for being recognizable*
   This is perhaps the more key reason why state cannot be part of the universe but at most be part of our understanding of it

### Some Examples

#### An Elevator

Take an elevator. We may take one of its states to be, for example,

> *Being stationary on the 3rd floor with both doors open*

We would not typically consider whether it is positioned 2 millimeters above or below the 3rd floor as a relevant to the state.

But is that true?

If we were looking at it from the pov of the central controller of the elevator, the above state and its simplifying assumption would be fine.

But now consider that the elevator company E say, subcontracts the brakes of its motor to another company B.

Now an [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) between E and B might very well run like this:

> *Being within 3 millimeters of the floor level is fine; being more than 6 is not; between 3 and 6 is a margin of error*

So when we are talking of the models between E and B, 2 mm matters, the door open or closed — probably not.

#### Computers

State is very fundamental to computers. A very basic primitive element of computer state is whether a certain "memory location" (bit) has a 1 or a 0 stored.

But the 1/0 are likely represented as 3V/0V.
Now suddenly we are jerked from the tidy digital world to the messy analog world — what margin of analog-3V should be digital-1?

Computer folks never think of this. Chip designers have to — See [Strong vs weak zero and one](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece410/mason/files/Ch2.pdf).

Speaking of "memory location" is there any such thing?
At a lower level there are just logic gates.
At a still lower level there are just transistors.
At a still lower level there is **just one wafer of silicon** and dope.

Each of these is a choice of model; none of them is **THE** model ie reality!

### In short...

> Reality is changing its state

No! Our models change state. And the appropriate model is chosen for the task at hand